# Cardinality of the union of infinitely many countable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We know that the union of countably many countable sets is countable.
What can se say about the union of infinitely many countable sets and its cardinality?
Thanks :)

Comment: Are countable sets not infinite?

Comment: Not necessarily

Comment: Sorry, of course. What I meant to say was -- can't countable sets be infinite?

Comment: Doesn`t the answer depend on whether the union is countable union or uncountable union?

Comment: I assume that when you say there are 'infinitely many', you mean non-countably many? because as you say yourself, if there are infinitely, yet still countably many countable sets, their union will still be countable.

Comment: I suspect the cardinality of the union is the same as the cardinality of the 'number' of countable sets that are being unioned .... But I have no proof ...

Comment: @Bram28 That's the point of the question! excuse me if I wrote it in an ambiguous way

Comment: The set $\mathbb N$ of all natural numbers has uncountably many countable subsets, and it is the union of all those countable subsets. So, the union of uncountably many countable sets ***can*** be countable. Maybe you want to assume that the sets are disjoint?

Comment: @bof yeah, good example ... We should probably assume they are disjoint. ... And containing at least one element ... Otherwise you could still have uncountably many empty sets ...

Comment: This question betrays a complete lack of effort. The problem is easily solved without any reference.

Answer (score 2):

The cardinality of a union of an infinite collection $\mathscr{S}$ of countably infinite sets is infinite, and is at most equal to the cardinality $\lvert\mathscr{S}\rvert$ of that collection.

That is:

> Suppose $\mathscr{S}$ is an infinite set of countably infinite sets. Then
>   $$
> \aleph_0 \le \left\lvert\bigcup \mathscr{S}\right\rvert \le \left\lvert \mathscr{S}\right\rvert.
> $$

The first inequality is clear. For the second, note that 
$$\begin{align}
\left\lvert \mathscr{S}\right\rvert &= \max(\left\lvert \mathscr{S}\right\rvert, \aleph_0) \\
&= \left\lvert \mathscr{S} \right\rvert \left\lvert \omega \right\rvert \tag{cardinal multiplication} \\
&= \left\lvert \mathscr{S} \times \omega \right\rvert.
\end{align}$$
Let $D$ be the (or, *a*) disjoint union of the sets in $\mathscr{S}$:
$$
D = \{(S, x) \mid x\in S \in \mathscr{S}\}.
$$
Then $\left\lvert D \right\rvert = \left\lvert \mathscr{S} \times \omega \right\rvert = \left\lvert \mathscr{S}\right\rvert$. From this, the inequality follows, because the usual function
$$
(S, x)\mapsto x \colon D \to \bigcup \mathscr{S}
$$
is a surjection.

Answer (score 1):

The real numbers is the union of the singletons drawn from the real numbers. These are countable sets but the union is uncountable. In general the disjoint union of k (k greater than aleph null) countable sets (not the null set) has cardinality k.

Answer (score 0):

The set $\mathbb N \times \mathbb R$ is the set of all ordered pairs $(n,x)$ where $n\in \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and $x$ is a real number. The set of pairs $\{(1,x), (2,x), (3,x),\ldots\}$ where $x$ is *just one* real number is countably infinite, so the union $\displaystyle \bigcup_{x\,\in\,\mathbb R} \{(1,x), (2,x), (3,x),\ldots\}$ is that of infinitely many countable sets. That is has at *most* as many members as $\mathbb R$ is seen by considering that the mapping
$$
(n,x) \mapsto n + \frac{1}{1 + 2^x}.
$$
That that union has *at least* as many members as $\mathbb R$ is seen by the fact that $\{(n,x):x\in\mathbb R\}$ (with just one fixed value of $n$) has as many members are $\mathbb R$.

If it has at most as many members as $\mathbb R$ and also at least as many, does it then have exactly as many as $\mathbb R$? With finite sets, the answer to that is trivially "yes". With infinite sets, the affirmative answer is the [Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem).